# Binding an img srcset with an array and data object in Vue.js

Tags: arrays, image, vue.js, responsive-design, responsive-images

I have a list of image names in an array, but I want to prefix them with a host and add some fun sizing options for responsive.  Here is what I have:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#gallery_images',
  data: {
    desktop: 'w=400&h=400&fit=crop&crop=faces,entropy&auto=format,compress 400w,',
    ipad: 'w=600&h=600&fit=crop&crop=faces,entropy&auto=format,compress 600w,',
    mobile: 'w=900&h=900&fit=crop&crop=faces,entropy&auto=format,compress 900w,',
    responsive: 'w=1200&h=1200&fit=crop&crop=faces,entropy&auto=format,compress 1200w',
    host: 'https://tom.imgix.net/artsy/',
    images: [ '1.jpg?', '2.jpg?', '3.jpg?', '4.jpg?', '5.jpg?', '6.jpg?']
  }
});
```

I am able to do some clumsy v-bind in the html and this works:

```
<div id="gallery_images">  
<img v-for="image, in images" :src="'https://tom.imgix.net/artsy/' + image" v-bind:srcset="host + image + desktop + host + image + ipad + host + image + mobile + host + image + responsive" sizes="(min-width: 1240px) 33vw, 100vw"/>
</div>
```

[Codepen]https://codepen.io/daletom/pen/WNvNgOa
This actually works!  But I think there is a better way. Instead of having to write all this host+image+size+host+image+size on and on.  It would be nice if I could just do a function for that and use it on all my pages in my website easily.

So I tried to build this.  I was thinking maybe add a computed function:

```
computed: {
    vueSDK: function () {
      return this.host + this.images + this.desktop + this.host + this.images + this.ipad + this.host + this.images + this.mobile + this.host + this.images + this.responsive
    }
  }
```

Then just pass the function in the srcset:

```
<div id="gallery_images">  
<img v-for="image, in images" :src="host + image" v-bind:srcset="vueSDK" sizes="(min-width: 1240px) 33vw, 100vw"/>
</div>
```

But that ain't working. It's just returning the same first image over and over.  You can see in this [codepen]https://codepen.io/daletom/pen/QWbJKPp

Is there an eloquent way to pass a function in the srcset to dynamically load in all these images with the various responsive sizing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you are only defining one single computed property per component. The `v-for` though requires a computed property for each iteration. The easiest way to do that is to use a method instead of a computed variable (with the drawback of losing the cache of a computed variable). If you looped through child components, you could also have a computed variable in each of those child components. I would prefer the second option. Here are examples of these two options:

## Using a method

```
<template>
  <img v-for="image in images" :src="host + image" :srcset="getSrcset(image)" sizes="(min-width: 1240px) 33vw, 100vw" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      host: ...,
      images: ...
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getSrcset () {
      return ...;
    }
  }
};
```

---

## Using a child component

In the parent component:

```
<custom-image v-for="image in images" :image="image" />
```

And the child component:

```
<template>
  <img :src="host + image" :srcset="srcset" sizes="(min-width: 1240px) 33vw, 100vw" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: 'image',
  data () {
    return {
      host: ...
    }
  },
  computed: {
    srcset () {
      return ...
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure what I'm missing, but tried to do this with the method option here: https://codepen.io/daletom/pen/QWbJKPp.  As for using a Child component, don't quite understand how to build that out in a codepen.  Where would I put the parent component?

Comment: actually got the method option to work doing this: ```methods: {
    vueSDK2: function (i) {
      console.log(i);
      return this.host + this.images[i] + this.desktop + this.host + this.images[i] + this.mobile;
    }
  }```. then for html, <img v-for="image, i in images" :src="host + image" :srcset="vueSDK2(i)"

Comment: Yes, this seems to work (using a method). If you want to use a child component without .vue files (directly inline, e.g  in a codepen), you can define a component with `Vue.component('custom-image', { computed: { ... }, template: '<img...', ... })` and then use this in the parent template.

Comment: In your example, it's better not to pass the index, but directly the `image` to the function. With that, you don't need to know in the function, what the index represents, but you directly have the image.